# Avoid counting array elements in function call

Tags: c++, typedef, function-call

I'm defining a function signature in order to perform a remote procedure call. Due to `undefined behavior`, I cannot increment the index variable in the call expression so I ended up counting from `0` to the last index and passed each to the function as argument. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this without counting? I was thinking about a loop or something. This would come in handy when the fixed arguments count changes to e.g. `16` arguments instead of `8`.

```
typedef unsigned long long int functionType(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);

unsigned long long int call_address(uintptr_t real_address, const unsigned int *arguments) {
    auto function = (functionType *) real_address;

    // We count instead of incrementing an index variable because: operation on 'argumentIndex' may be undefined
    return function(arguments[0], arguments[1],
                    arguments[2], arguments[3],
                    arguments[4], arguments[5],
                    arguments[6], arguments[7]);
}
```

I know there are [variable arguments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm) using `va_start`, `va_list` and `va_end` but I'm not sure if they can be used here.

Comment: Please pick one language. Also, read the descriptions of tags that you apply.

Comment: What about passing a pointer to the first array element (a.k.a. the array itself) and a second parameter with the count of elements? Depending on the RPC framework there should be a description language like `IDL` that allows to tell the framework that more than one array element has to be transferred.

Comment: You're asking how to determine the parameter count "8" from the type `functionType`, or how to build a more general expression to call the function with that many array elements in the return statement, or both?

Comment: I'm asking how to build an expression which takes the function address, an array of arguments and the arguments count to perform the call without hard-coding the passed arguments by counting them off since counting does not work with a variable arguments count of integers

Comment: How would ”incrementing an index variable” solve your problem if it were well defined?

Comment: It doesn't solve this problem but it removes the need to count the indices in the source code which is slightly better than how it is now.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Why does your `function()` need to take individual arguments like this, instead of an array with a defined size as another argument? This doesn't seem natural or correct. What kind of RPC are you using? This won't work because you want to mix compile-time (number of parameters of the function) and run-time (the number of elements in the array). Your RPC is either broken or you don't know how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A part of your solution involves unpacking a fixed amount of values from your `arguments` array and calling `function` with it. The following C++14 code will do that:

```
template <typename F, size_t... Is>
unsigned long long int our_invoke(F f, const unsigned int * args, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return f(args[Is]...);
}

unsigned long long int call_address(uintptr_t real_address, const unsigned int *arguments) {
    auto function = (functionType *) real_address;

    return our_invoke(function, arguments, std::make_index_sequence<8>{});
}
```